# Store private key on a static Angular site

Tags: node.js, security, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static AngularJS file. It's deployed on Amazon S3. 
I am accessing a API which has a hash authentication mechanism.

I have to use a private key in order to create a hash of the URL and send on the header. It works great, but the problem is that I have to find a way to keep the private key out of the reach of hackers.

I would like to know if anyone knows a way to keep the key secure.

I have thought about running my site on a node.js server. The only requirement is that I should be able to deploy it on Amazon web services.

Does it make sense?

Comment: So, you have a private key that you would like to use directly from the client side browser?

Comment: On every request I am encrypting the URL before making the CORS request and sending on a header. The requirement is that I need to send an encrypted header on the request. At this moment I have no way to hide the private key that I am using to generate the encrypted header. If you know a better way of doing this let me know.

Comment: Ask your server for the header.  Keep the private key on the server.  AFAIK, there is no secure way to store a private key in the browser.

Comment: I don't have a server right now. I think that I will have a node.js server. Is it the right way? Even if I ask the key to the server, it will be available in memory, how can I fix that?

Comment: No, I didn't say ask the server for the key.  I said ask the server for the header (already encrypted by the key).  Again, to my knowledge, this is the only way to protect the key.

Comment: If your node.js server is running on an EC2 instance, it can use an IAM role. It will automatically find credentials to make the service calls as needed, without you having to provide them. The credentials get rotated frequently, to prevent them being used outside the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a secure way to store secrets on client side. Private keys should always stay in the server.

The common authentication mechanism for APIs is to hash (not encrypt) authentication on client side.

But if you need encrypt something, you should use a asymmetric encryption algorithm with a public key on client.

http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/asymmetric-cryptography

Comment: I want to hash on client side. But in order to hash I need a private key. I am using HMAC-SHA1. Any help?

Comment: @Tony you could encrypt either with public or private key. Take a look on the [Crypto-JS library](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)